# Prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, projective-module

Prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Suppose on the contrary that $\mathbb{C}$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then we have that $\mathbb{C}$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$. So, the inclusion would send one in $\mathbb{C}$ to one in $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$. Then, $i(n/n)=n \hspace{0.02 in}i(1/n)$ implies that $(1/n)^{(I)}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$, a contradiction. Is this proof correct?

Comment: Why does the inclusion have to send $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$? What does the latter even mean if $I$ is infinite?

Comment: @AlexWertheim You are right, it's meaningless in direct sum. It does not have to! correct!

Comment: Anyway, it's late for me and I might be making a silly mistake, but I think you can rescue your approach with a small tweak. Note that multiplication by $n$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ for every integer $n$. Hence, if $\mathbb{C}$ were isomorphic to a submodule of some $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$, then some nonzero submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$ must also have this property. But you can see that no submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$ does: for any submodule, pick an element with the smallest (abs. value) coordinate; this can't be in the image of any nontrivial multiplication map.

Comment: (This is really just your idea, but instead of focusing on 1 in either the domain or codomain, you pick the element of the image of $\mathbb{C}$ in $Z^{(I)}$ with the smallest coordinate, and then run your exact same argument.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim You meant $\mathbb{C}$ is divisible but $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$ has no divisible submodule, right?

Answer (score 1):

The proof has the right idea but is not quite correct: the same logic shows that $\Bbb Z$ is not a $\Bbb Z$-module since $n=n(1/n)$ implies $1/n\in\Bbb Z$.

What you are getting at is divisibility: an $R$-module $V$ is divisible if $rV=V$ for all $r$ which are not zero divisors.

Over $\Bbb Z$, any free module is not divisible (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653760/free-module-over-the-integers) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853153/prove-that-no-mathbbz-module-is-both-projective-and-injective)). If $\Bbb C$ is free, this means that there exists $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $z\in\Bbb C$ for which $nz\notin\Bbb C$. Of course this is impossible since $\Bbb Z$ is a subring of $\Bbb C$ already. In other words, $\Bbb C$ is clearly divisible, hence not a free $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: I guess I figured out. The image of $\mathbb{C}$ under a projection would have a non-zero divisible submodule of $\mathbb{Z}$ itself, which is a contradiction. @pancini